# How can I select elements with no id or class?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to select an element within an element, essentially. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="first">
      <div></div>
      <div><!-- the element I want to select --></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried one method, which looks like this:

```
function findFirstDescendant(parent, tagname) {
  parent = document.getElementsByClassName(parent)[0];
  var descendants = parent.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
  if (descendants.length)
    return descendants[0];
  return null;
}
```

and also this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("first")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[1];
```

Neither work, as the method seems to be outdated. I would like to keep jQuery out of this, but it is acceptable if there is no other solution.

Comment: Your second attempt appears to work as expected for me in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/ay4a990L/

Comment: It seems like a browser compatibility issue. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @shaochuancs I'm using the tampermonkey extension on Chrome.

Comment: Does my fiddle correctly log the element in question for you?

Comment: Tampermonkey is just a script manager extension, not a browser. Can you disable Tampermonkey and try again?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yes, it does. I believe the issue is the elements are loading in after the script is run. I'll try adding a delay to the startup.

Comment: @shaochuancs The script is being run by tampermonkey. I tried adding in the code into the browser with and without it enabled, both worked. This leads me to believe the script is running to early.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The script itself works well.

Comment: I put in the answer with the delay and an alternative, but similar approach. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting anyone's time. I feel a little dumb for not thinking of this sooner. I fixed the problem by adding a 250ms delay to the script, as it was being executed before the page fully loaded. My code was similar to this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("card-player")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  console.log(a);
}, 250);
```

You could also add in more variables if you wanted to debug or log more information like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("first")[0];
  var b = a.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];
  var c = b.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];
  var d = b.getElementsByTagName("div")[2];
}, 250);
```

Comment: You should put your `javascript` code at the bottom of your page or your code in `document.onload = function(){ /*code here*/ }` instead of using a delay.

Comment: `setTimeout` is a very bad solution. Use an IIFE, `window.onload` or `DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use `querySelector` to take advantage of CSS selectors...

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.first > div:nth-child(2)');
console.log(el);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="first">
      <div></div>
      <div>Hello!</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But obviously, you can use this more classical solution too:

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
console.log(el);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="first">
      <div></div>
      <div>Hello!</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```